# Evaluating a double integral with a max-function

Tags: calculus, integration

I am trying to solve an integral that is a bit beyond my math skills. The integral is given by:

\begin{align}
F(z) &= k \iint_{x^2+y^2 \leq r^2} \max\left( z_0(x,y)-z, 0\right) dx dy \\
z_0(x,y) &= r-\sqrt{r^2 - x^2 - y^2}
\end{align}

As we can see, for $z$ large the solution should become zero; while for $-z$ large the solution should become $F(z) = c - k A z$ where $c$ is a constant and $A$ is the area of a circle with radius $r$. Solving the integral for the solution between these limits is where I am stuck.

My questions are as follows:

- Does an algebraic solution even exist for $F(z)$?
- If so, what is the solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the integration variables to polar coordinates $x=\rho \cos\theta$ and $y=\rho\sin\theta$. The Jacobian of the transformation is $\rho$. Your integral gets transformed into
$$
F(z,r)=k\int_0^r d\rho\rho\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta \max(r-\sqrt{r^2-\rho^2}-z,0)\ .
$$
(Note that $F(z)$ is more properly a function of both $z$ and $r$).
Now we need to understand for what values of $\rho$
$$
r-\sqrt{r^2-\rho^2}-z>0\ ,
$$
for the other values the integral being zero. The inequality can be solved and yields two cases:

1) for $z<0$, $\rho$ must be between $0< \rho\leq r$. Therefore you need to solve
$$
F(z<0,r)=k\int_0^r d\rho\rho\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta \left[r-\sqrt{r^2-\rho^2}-z\right]=\pi k\frac{r^2}{3}(r-3z)\ .
$$
2) for $z>0$, the solutions of the previous inequality requires $r>z$ and $\sqrt{2rz-z^2}<\rho\leq r$, therefore
$$
F(z>0,r>z)=k\int_{\sqrt{2rz-z^2}}^r d\rho\rho\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta \left[r-\sqrt{r^2-\rho^2}-z\right]=\pi k \frac{(r-z)^3}{3}\ .
$$ 
For $0<r<z$, we have $F(z,r)=0$.